# Why address of variable remain same in fork() system call after it is modified

Tags: operating-system

Consider the following code snippet.

```
if (fork() == 0)
{
     a = a + 5;
     printf("%d, %d \n", a, &a);
}
else
{
     a = a - 5;
     printf ("%d, %d \n", a,& a);
}
```

AFAIK, when fork() is made, the virtual address space of parent is copied to the child and both child & parent share the same physical pages until one of them tries to modify. The moment one of the child & parent modifies a variable, the physical page of parent is copied to another page for child and the physical pages remain private.
So, here value of 'a' is different in child & parent. But when it comes for the addresses of 'a' in child & parent, the output is same. I am not able to figure out why the address remains same even if the physical pages are diffrent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The address of `a` is not the actual physical address.

It is a virtual address.
The hardware/OS layer maps virtual addresses to physical addresses (invisibly to your application).

So even though the addresses have the same `number` they do not map to the same physical memory on your ram chip.

PS. When printing the address (ie pointer) using printf() best to use "%p"

Comment: It means whatever we see is the virtual address. Can we see the actual physical address through our program?

Comment: If you get the correct (OS) tools. But under normal circumstances no.

Answer (score 3):

The response is almost in your question: the physical page of `a` is copied (and thus not the same as in the parent process) after modifying `a`, but the virtual address (what's seen by your program, through `&a`) does not change.

In fact it would be very awkward to change the virtual address of `a` when assigning it a new value. Consider what happens if you had previously stored a pointer to `a`:

```
 int *p = &a;
 a = a - 5;
 printf("%d", *p)
```

After the second line p would not point to `a` anymore, a behaviour that no programmer would expect.

The use of copy-on-write for physical pages is an optimization of the OS that is irrelevant to the behavior of your program: you can consider that the entire address space is copied when you fork.